# Selecting Rows That Have One Value but Not Another

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a get some rows of two tables with join that shoud have one value in a column (1407)  but shouldn't have other value (1403)

These is the tables and the query:

```
select a.job, a.date, b.group  from log a inner join active_tmp b
on a.jobno=b.jobno and a.no=b.no where b.list = 'N'
AND LOGDATE = TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'YYYYMMDD')
and a.job not like 'HOUSE%'
and a.job not like 'CAR%' and (errorCode=1047 and errorCode<>1403);


LOG
JOB     DATE        LOGDATE     JOBNO       NO  errorCode
MAM  20220123       20220125       33       22  1047
MAM  20220123       20220125       33       22  1403
DAD  20220122       20220125       11       99  1047
MAM  20220122       20220125       33       22  0323
DAD  20220122       20220125       11       99  0444   




ACTIVE_TMP
JOB      JOBNO          NO    GROUP     LIST  
MAM         33          22    LAPTOP    N     
MAM         33          22    LAPTOP    N     
DAD         11          99    KEY       N     

But I get:
MAM,20220123,LAPTOP
DAD,20220122,KEY
```

I need:

```
DAD,20220122,KEY
```

Because MAM have both codes (1047 and 1043).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase, I think you mean "I want to return matching rows that have error code 1047 but for which the same values of jobno, no, list do not have a corresponding row with error code 1403"

This part is redundant:

```
AND   (errorCode = 1047 AND errorCode <> 1403);
```

If you are saying errorCode must be 1047, you are also saying it is not equal to 1403.

I think you want to select some rows into some result set, then check that there's not another row that disqualifies one of the selected rows from the final result.

So,

```
SELECT a.job,
       a.date,
       b.group
FROM _log a
  INNER JOIN _active_tmp b
          ON a.jobno = b.jobno
         AND a.no = b.no
WHERE b.list = 'N'
AND   LOGDATE = TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDD')
AND   a.job NOT LIKE 'HOUSE%'
AND   a.job NOT LIKE 'CAR%'
AND   a.errorCode = 1047
AND   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM _log c
                    INNER JOIN _active_tmp d
                            ON c.jobno = d.jobno
                           AND c.no = d.no
                  WHERE a.job = c.job
                  AND   a.date = c.date
                  AND   b.group = d.group
                  AND   c.errorCode = 1403)
```

We select the rows that satisfy the join and have error code 1047 then subtract from that set those rows that also satisfy the join but have error code 1403. You could possibly make this more terse using CTE or a temp table, but this works too.

Note I had to change a few things to make it work in my engine (Postgres), so you may have to change a few things back to Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the error code logic. Identify what `JOB` values has `1403` and then exclude those values

```
select distinct a.job, a.date, b.[group]  from LOG a inner join active_tmp b
on a.jobno=b.jobno and a.no=b.no where b.list = 'N'
AND LOGDATE = TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'YYYYMMDD')
and a.job not like 'HOUSE%'
and a.job not like 'CAR%' and a.job not in (select JOB from log where  errorCode in(1403));
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I had a job without 1043 and 1047 codes I think with your query show me that register and I don't want that register . Right?

Comment: add another condition `and a.job = 1407`